# How to create White Square and Transparent Circle inside the square using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I want to create Image like below. Can someone show me how to do this in Photoshop?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: By transparent, do you mean you want to cut it out of the rectangle?

Answer (score 2):

There may be several ways to achieve this, but this is my preferred method:

1. Open up a canvas of a suitable size.
2. Select the **Rectangle Tool** (<kbd>U</kbd>)
3. Holding the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key, draw a square to a size of your liking. *Note, make sure you are making a shape **shape layer***
4. Now get the **Elipse Tool** (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>)
5. Have your cursor on the bottom left corner of the square, and holding <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, drag up to the top right corner of the square
6. <kbd>CRTL</kbd> click on the circle layer, then apply a layer mask to the square layer.

I think I understood what you are saying correctly. If not than, do everything up till step 5, then just set the "fill opacity" of the circle layer to 0.

Hope this helps. (: